# insertion sort using clojure

Tags: clojure

I ran into this error when I try to evaluate the last line below: "No message. [Thrown class java.lang.NullPointerException]"

```
(defn my-insertion-sort [lst]
  (loop [list lst result '()]
    (if-not (seq? list) result
            (recur (rest list) (my-insert (first list) result)))))

(defn my-insert [n lst]
  (cond (nil? lst) (list n)
        (> (first lst) n) (conj lst n)
        :else
        (conj (my-insert n (rest lst)) (first lst))))

(my-insertion-sort '(2 1 3))
```

Where goes wrong with "my-insertion-sort" function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(defn my-insertion-sort [lst]
  (loop [list lst result '()]
    (if (empty? list) result
        (recur (rest list) (my-insert (first list) result)))))

(defn my-insert [n lst]
  (cond 
    (empty? lst) (list n)
    (> (first lst) n) (conj lst n)
    :else (conj (my-insert n (rest lst)) (first lst))))
```

Comment: okay, this works. So what is the why change (nil? __) and (not (seq? __)) to (empty ?) make this difference?

Comment: I summarize this into another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025124/what-is-the-difference-between-seq-and-seq

Comment: You can try (nil? ()) and (empty? ()). You used (rest lst), and (rest ()) is (), not nil.