# Why prefer seq over non-empty as a predicate?

Tags: clojure

The docstring for `empty?` says "Please use the idiom (seq x) rather than (not (empty? x))".  [MisterMetaphor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025124/what-is-the-difference-between-seq-and-seq) points out that using `seq` as a predicate can make sense when used in `if-let`:

```
(if-let [s (seq might-be-empty)]
   (fn-for-non-empty-seq s)
   (fn-for-empty-seq))
```

Should I really use `seq` to test for non-emptiness in general, though?  `seq` may convert its argument to a different form.  For example:

```
user=> (class (lazy-seq '(1 2 3)))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
user=> (class (seq (lazy-seq '(1 2 3))))
clojure.lang.PersistentList
user=> (class (map inc [1 2 3]))
clojure.lang.LazySeq
user=> (class (seq (map inc [1 2 3])))
clojure.lang.ChunkedCons
```

That seems like a waste of cycles if just want to test for non-emptiness, and don't need a new binding, or if I don't need the conversion before the binding.  Wouldn't `not-empty` be a better choice in such cases?  It returns `nil` if its argument is empty, and its argument unchanged if non-empty.

```
(if (not-empty [])
  "more to do"
  "all done")
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, check out the definition of `empty?`:

```
(defn empty?
  "Returns true if coll has no items - same as (not (seq coll)).
  Please use the idiom (seq x) rather than (not (empty? x))"
  {:added "1.0"
  :static true}
  [coll] (not (seq coll)))
```

So `empty?` *is* `(not (seq coll))`. That's why it's discouraged to complement `empty?`, because you are doing a double negation on `seq`.

Now see `not-empty`

```
(defn not-empty
  "If coll is empty, returns nil, else coll"
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  [coll] (when (seq coll) coll))
```

Surprise, it uses `seq` as the test of non-emptiness too. This `not-empty` *is* useful if the type matters -- `nth` performance on vectors, `conj` behavior, etc. -- because it does return non-empty colls as is. Used as just a predicate though, it would only be wrapping `seq`.

Don't worry about `seq` being heavy-handed though. It does little more than return an iterator. It does not actually convert the entire data structure.

Comment: Thanks. Fascinating, and surprising, that any extra cost at all (returning the iterator) is required to be paid for an operation used so often.  Or rather, it must be that in fact it is no cost at all, which again, is fascinating.

Comment: I sure hope the JIT compiler doesn't have a problem with optimizing a double negation.

Comment: @remicles2 I can't imagine optimizations in dynamically typed languages with lazy fragments to be all that hot. Are there any paper saying how much work the JIT is even able to do before it hits some major hurdle?