# Why use empty over count?

Tags: clojure

To determine whether a [Clojure list](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Lists) has any items wouldn't it be more efficient (space + memory-wise) to use `(zero? (count coll))` over `(empty? coll)` which creates a seq?

Asking because [the docs show](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) a list as one of the examples.

Comment: `seq` is apparently a very inexpensive operation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21595212/1455243

Answer (score 7):

`count` itself is not always the constant time function:

```
user> (time (count (take 1000000 (iterate inc 0))))
;;=> "Elapsed time: 185.544391 msecs"
```

moreover, for example `(count (range))` won't even complete.

while `empty?` uses `seq` which creates sequence, but still it doesn't copy it's contents, so it is a constant time function (and since the clojure's data structures are designed with contents structural sharing, the memory penalty is not really big):

```
user> (time (empty? (take 1000000 (iterate inc 0))))
;;=> "Elapsed time: 0.254139 msecs"
```

you could also think of using `(= () (take 1 coll))`, but i don't think it would do any better than plain `empty?`

Comment: [`counted?`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6182) returns whether its collection argument responds to `count` in constant time.

Comment: When I said list I meant [list](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Lists) which is constant time for `count` (shown in that link + http://www.innoq.com/blog/st/2010/04/clojure-performance-guarantees/) yet the [example for `empty?`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/empty_q) also uses a list. it makes sense that `count` on a lazy sequence is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

(This is an appendix to [Leetwinski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57003839/1562315).)

Clojure improves upon previous Lisps (IMO) by having a single set of functions to manipulate all kinds of [sequences](https://clojure.org/reference/sequences): lazy or not, indexed or not.

Try not to depend upon a sequential collection being of a particular kind (a list, in your case). You could get ambushed by a client supplying a sequence of the wrong kind.

For example, you might think that `cons` upon a list would return a list. It doesn't. It returns a `clojure.lang.Cons`, *which is not `counted?`*. When the code starts running slowly, I don't fancy finding out that a `count` call is causing the problem.